# Dense sets in $L_{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

I know that for every probability measure $\mu$ on doubling metric space $X$, 
the set of lipschitz functions (and therefore continuous functions) is dense in $L_1(\mu)$. Is it true for $L_{\infty}$ as well? i.e. for every $\epsilon >0$ and a bounded function $g$ there is a continuous $f$ s.t. for all $x \in X$ we have 
$|f(x) - g(x)| <\epsilon $  (I assume $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$)

If it is not true, is it correct with additional constraints on $X$?

Comment: Typically it's false ($X=(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure, say), $L^{\infty}$, being non-separable, is too big for that: if you write $X$ as a disjoint union union of sets $X_n$ with positive measure, then the uncountably many functions $f=\sum a_n \chi_{X_n}$ with $a_n=0,1$ are all at distance $1$ of each other in $L^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False even in very nice spaces like $[0,1]$. It is known that pointwise limits of continuous functions are continuous at points of a dense set. Since a bounded (measurable) function need not be continuous at any point we cannot write it as a pointwise limit of continuous functions.